# while creating and adding objects to a vector in a loop always adds same object

Tags: c++

I got a problem,

```
class student {
public:
    static int id,a,c;
    static bool editable;
    static std::queue <int> classes;
    static queue <int> classesT;
    static queue <int> classesD;
public:
    student(int x,int y,queue <int> z){
        editable=true;
        id=x;
        a=y;
        classes=z;
        c=classes.size();
    }

    void DisposeObject()
    {
       delete this;
    }
};

int main(){
std::vector <queue <int> >links;
std::vector <int> quotas;
std::vector <student> sList;
std::queue <int> classes;
std::queue <student> q1;
int a,c,sNum,cNum;
static int temp;
ifstream myFile("....");
if(myFile.is_open()){
    myFile>>sNum;
    myFile>>cNum;
}
for(int i=0;i<sNum;i++){
    myFile>>c;
    myFile>>a;
    for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
    myFile>>temp;
    classes.push(temp);
    }
    student *s1=new student(i,a,classes);
    sList.push_back(*s1);
    s1->DisposeObject();
    while(!classes.empty())
        classes.pop();
}
```

This is my code. I want to add different objects to my vector but whenever a new student created students that created before take its values and I end up with a vector something like:

```
a,a,a,a
```

instead of

```
a,b,c,d
```

By the way I already tried reserve function.

Comment: Why are you using new if the vector doesn't contain pointers?  Can you show a complete example?

Comment: Are you sure you're reading different information from `myFile` during each iteration? If you end up with four instances of `student` in the vector, it means that the `push_back`s work but the information stored with the objects is incorrect. Also, why do you `new` the student? You can just as easily `push_back` a temporary and spare yourself the clean-up: `sList.push_back(student(i,a,classes));` Also, does `DisposeObject()` commit sucicide, i.e. does it do `delete this`? Otherwise, you have a leak with every single `student` you `new` up. (Note: I don't recommend suicide!).

Comment: @user3106529 have you debugged your code? btw, where is the `delete s1`?

Comment: What is sList storing, s or *s?

Comment: @MartinJames: If it stored `student*`, `push_back(*(student*))` wouldn't compile.

Comment: And is `student` copying `classes`?  It seems like if you just declare `vector<whatever> classes` inside your `for(int i...)` loop, you'd get a fresh one each iteration.  Your `while() pop` loop just seems either unnecessary or wrong.

Comment: @JoeZ: With the OPs current implementation it's not wrong, because all classes must be gone for the next iteration to produce a valid list of classes for student `i + 1`. It is, however, unnecessary and inconvenient - that's what `std::vector::clear()` is for. Still, I'd create a local instance of `std::vector<class>` as well - unless it shows significant performance impact to do so.

Comment: @thokra:  My point was that if `student` was just keeping a pointer or reference to the `vector`, then all the instances of `student` will have the same `classes` in the end, which is bad.  If `student` copies the vector, then there are better ways to clear out `classes` (either by getting a fresh instance every iteration or by calling `clear`) than that while loop.

Comment: @JoeZ: Agreed, but the implementation of `ctor` invoked on the instance of `student` is orthogonal to the rest of the code - which, even if clumsy, seems to be at least semantically correct.

Comment: I added the student class and main until it comes adding to a vector part I hope this give a clearer look about problem

Comment: `std::queue<>`, interesting.  I don't think a queue buys you much over `std::vector<>` where you're using it.  For example, it's now clearer why you have that `while` loop to empty it, though.

Answer (score 1):

The code isn't sufficient to pin-point exactly what the problem is. However, there are multiple things which are, at least, suspicious:

1. You don't check any of your inputs and just *assume* everything went well! My personal guess is that reading failed at the end of the first or the beginning of the second record and you just reuses the already read values. You **always** want to check your reads **after** you attempted to read, e.g.:

   ```
   if (myFile >> a >> c) {
        // carry on
   }
   else {
       std::cout << "ERROR: failed to read record!\n";
       // recover, bail out, ...
   }
   ```
2. In C++ you **don't** allocate objects on the heap unless you absolutely have to! Most of the time, you get away with some classes doing the allocation for you. I can't remember when I last used `new` in application code. Here is how you can append a `student` record:

   ```
   sList.push_back(student(i, a, classes));
   ```

   The object will, conveniently, clean-up after itself. That is, quickly, get rid of your `DisposeObject()` member function! C++ uses destructors and neatly do so because it isn't garbage collected. Do not try to carry over C# idioms to C++: it won't do you any good.
3. There is no need to remove every object individually from your vector. Just use `clear()`:

   ```
   classes.clear();
   ```

Comment: I'd add that `void DisposeObject() { delete this; }` is a pretty bad idea.  The restrictions you must adhere to to "get it right" are pretty onerous: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/delete-this.html